# Cart Price Rule Condition is not working

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

I am trying to show Free Shipping only for this SKU but its not working below is my condition

[image]

but the free shipping is visible on All products including above mention sku.

Comment: Set Free Shipping to “For shipment with matching items.” & Disable the free shipping in general

Comment: tried that, but its still not working

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-setup-free-shipping-promotion-in-magento-2.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you disabled the free shipping in general?

Go to Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Shipping Methods -> Free Shipping. Set Free Shipping Enabled to "No" and see if the free shipping is working only for your product.

Regards.

Comment: if i disable the free shipping from configuration then how it will work?

Comment: You have set the free shipping rule for your product. By disabling the free shipping in general, your rule must be work too.

Comment: tried that too, but it does not seems to be working

Comment: Please set the Priority in your Rule from 0 to 1, clear the cache and see if it's working. Keep the Fre Shipping in the Configuration Disabled.

Comment: priority is already set to 1